# Phaser not rendering objects created in group

Tags: javascript, web, rendering, phaser-framework, 2d-games

I'm new to phaser and I can't seem to make the object created visible no matter what.

Here is the JS code:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(448, 448, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, 
create: create, update: update });



function  preload () {
    game.load.image('tabuleiro','assets/tabuleiro.png')
    game.load.spritesheet('devil','assets/devil.png',32,32);
    var capetinhas;
}

function create (){

capetinhas = game.add.group();

game.add.sprite(window.width,0,'tabuleiro');  //loading the background


game.add.sprite(128,128,'devil'); // this works


capetinhas.create(32,32,'devil'); // this doesnt    

}

function update (){

}
```

When I put `capetinhas.countLiving()` on the console it prints 1, which means the object is created but not rendered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `var capetinhas;` outside of your preloader function so it has global scope. This just looks like a scope error - `capetinhas` is defined inside `preload()`, so `create()` can't access that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I believe I got it correct it’s unchecked but i changed several things just compare to yours.

```
//this will all go in one state 
var game = new Phaser.Game(448, 448, Phaser.AUTO, '', { 
    preload: preload, 
    create: create,
    update: update
});

var main={

    preload:function() {
        game.load.image('tabuleiro','assets/tabuleiro.png')
        game.load.spritesheet('devil','assets/devil.png',32,32);

    },

    create:function (){
        this.capetinhas = game.add.group();
        game.add.sprite(window.width,0,'tabuleiro');  //loading the background
        game.add.sprite(128,128,'devil'); // this works
        this.capetinhas.create(32,32,'devil'); // this doesnt    
    },

    update:function (){
    },
};

var capetinhas;
```

I’m on mobile so I couldn’t check the functionality but try that if it’s not working then delete the create group part make a new function in between create and update call it Ex

```
evil: function(){ 
    // and in here do your group calls while using the “this.” So you can comunícate outside of the function
}
```